# Unresolved external '_main' referenced from C0X32.OBJ

Tags: c++, c, program-entry-point

```
#include <CkMailMan.h>
#include <CkEmail.h>
#include <stdio>
void ChilkatSample(void)
    {
//  The mailman object is used for sending and receiving email.
CkMailMan mailman;

//  Any string argument automatically begins the 30-day trial.
bool success;
success = mailman.UnlockComponent("30-day trial");
if (success != true) {
    printf("%s\n",mailman.lastErrorText());
    return;
}

//  Set the SMTP server.
mailman.put_SmtpHost("smtp.chilkatsoft.com");

//  Set the SMTP login/password (if required)
mailman.put_SmtpUsername("myUsername");
mailman.put_SmtpPassword("myPassword");

//  Create a new email object
CkEmail email;

email.put_Subject("This is a test");
email.put_Body("This is a test");
email.put_From("Chilkat Support <support@chilkatsoft.com>");
email.AddTo("Chilkat Admin","admin@chilkatsoft.com");
//  To add more recipients, call AddTo, AddCC, or AddBcc once per recipient.

//  Call SendEmail to connect to the SMTP server and send.
//  The connection (i.e. session) to the SMTP server remains
//  open so that subsequent SendEmail calls may use the
//  same connection.
success = mailman.SendEmail(email);
if (success != true) {
    printf("%s\n",mailman.lastErrorText());
    return;
}

//  Some SMTP servers do not actually send the email until
//  the connection is closed.  In these cases, it is necessary to
//  call CloseSmtpConnection for the mail to be  sent.
//  Most SMTP servers send the email immediately, and it is
//  not required to close the connection.  We'll close it here
//  for the example:
success = mailman.CloseSmtpConnection();
if (success != true) {
    printf("Connection to SMTP server not closed cleanly.\n");
}

printf("Mail Sent!\n");
}
```

I trying to send a STMP mail using Chilkat library. I am receiving an error: "Unresolved external '_main' referenced from C0X32.OBJ."

Comment: where is your main() ?

Comment: `#include <stdio>` is not a thing

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 4):

You need a `main()` function, that's the C entry point for (hosted) implementations.

It *may* be as simple as adding:

```
int main (void) {
    ChilkatSample();
    return 0;
}
```

to your code, or it may be a whole lot more complex.

But the bottom line is that your implementation startup code (in `C0X32.OBJ`) is trying to find `main` so it can start running your program proper.

---

In addition, if you're after the `stdio` header, you should be using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

rather than leaving off the extension as you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the program entry point i.e. int main()

Add the main function as below

```
int  main ( int arc, char **argv ) 
{
    ChilkatSample();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, your code should look like below and should be able to compile

```
#include <CkMailMan.h>
#include <CkEmail.h>
#include <stdio>
void ChilkatSample(void)
    {
//  The mailman object is used for sending and receiving email.
CkMailMan mailman;

//  Any string argument automatically begins the 30-day trial.
bool success;
success = mailman.UnlockComponent("30-day trial");
if (success != true) {
    printf("%s\n",mailman.lastErrorText());
    return;
}

//  Set the SMTP server.
mailman.put_SmtpHost("smtp.chilkatsoft.com");

//  Set the SMTP login/password (if required)
mailman.put_SmtpUsername("myUsername");
mailman.put_SmtpPassword("myPassword");

//  Create a new email object
CkEmail email;

email.put_Subject("This is a test");
email.put_Body("This is a test");
email.put_From("Chilkat Support <support@chilkatsoft.com>");
email.AddTo("Chilkat Admin","admin@chilkatsoft.com");
//  To add more recipients, call AddTo, AddCC, or AddBcc once per recipient.

//  Call SendEmail to connect to the SMTP server and send.
//  The connection (i.e. session) to the SMTP server remains
//  open so that subsequent SendEmail calls may use the
//  same connection.
success = mailman.SendEmail(email);
if (success != true) {
    printf("%s\n",mailman.lastErrorText());
    return;
}

//  Some SMTP servers do not actually send the email until
//  the connection is closed.  In these cases, it is necessary to
//  call CloseSmtpConnection for the mail to be  sent.
//  Most SMTP servers send the email immediately, and it is
//  not required to close the connection.  We'll close it here
//  for the example:
success = mailman.CloseSmtpConnection();
if (success != true) {
    printf("Connection to SMTP server not closed cleanly.\n");
}

printf("Mail Sent!\n");
}

int  main ( int arc, char **argv ) 
{
    ChilkatSample();
    return 0;
}
```